# Android: Open a custom file

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I get a Runtime Error if I want to open a file which cannot handle the Android, like .pm3 (instead of .mp3).

Runtime Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24095): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/download/ttt.pm3 }
```

Here is my code:

```
public void executeFile(FileItem fileItem) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(fileItem.getFilePath());

    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String ext = fileItem.getFileExtension();
    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);

    this.fileManagerActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I think that I should put an if before the this.fileManagerActivity.startActivity(intent); line.
But I don't know how could I check that.

So my question is that, how could I avoid this runtime error?

Thank you for the answers:)

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public void executeFile(FileItem fileItem) {

    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(fileItem.getFilePath());

        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = fileItem.getFileExtension();
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);

        this.fileManagerActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
    //Do your fallback
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if file name ends with .mp3

```
String patterncheck= ".mp3";
File file = new File(fileItem.getFilePath());
{
if(file.getName().endsWith(patterncheck))

}
```

Use the above tto check if filename ends with .mp3 and then use intent accordingly

```
public void executeFile(FileItem fileItem) {

String patterncheck= ".mp3";


File file = new File(fileItem.getFilePath());
{
if(file.getName().endsWith(patterncheck))
 {
 Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String ext = fileItem.getFileExtension();
String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);

this.fileManagerActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
       Toast.maketext(MainActivity.this,"Not an mp3",1000).show();
}
}
```